# Standard normal density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Please help me solve this problem:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent standard normal random variables, let $Z$ have an arbitrary density function, and form $Q = \frac{X + YZ}{\sqrt{1+ Z^2}}$. Prove that $Q$ also has a standard normal density function.

Thanh you

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For every real number $u$ in $(0,1)$, the random variable $Xu+Y\sqrt{1-u^2}$ is standard normal. Hence, for every $(0,1)$ valued random variable $U$ independent of $(X,Y)$, the random variable $XU+Y\sqrt{1-U^2}$ is standard normal. Use this for $U=1/\sqrt{1+Z^2}$.