Transformation of Gaussian random variables
Let $\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3$ be independent random variables,$\xi_i \sim N(0,1)$ .Show that
$$ \frac{\xi_1+\xi_2 \xi_3}{\sqrt{1+\xi^2_3}}\sim N(0,1)$$ I understand that this can be done by sequentially calculating the density for each operation, but it seems to me that there should be a simpler solution. I will be glad if you help me find it

See  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517894/standard-normal-
density-function and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262361/why-fracxyz-sqrt1z2-sim-mathcaln0-1-if-x-y-z-are-i-i-d-ma

The distribution of $\frac {\xi_1+\xi_2c}{\sqrt {1+c^{2}}}$ is $N(0, 1)$ for each constant $c$. Hence, the statement follows by conidtioning on $\xi_3$.
To be more explcit $P(\frac {\xi_1+\xi_2\xi_3}{\sqrt {1+\xi^{2}}}\le x)=\int P(\frac {\xi_1+\xi_2c}{\sqrt {1+c^{2}}} \le x) dF_{\xi_3}(c)=\int \Phi(x) dF_{\xi_3}(c)=\Phi (x)$.

Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure if it's correct. After all, then the distribution of the $\xi_3$ is completely unimportant

It is independent of the distribution of $\xi_3$ as long as the variables are independent. Tell me where my proof is wrong.
